# How to render list in react with smart reaction when block is removed/changed position?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Basic logic (in life it's redux store with immutable.js):

```
render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}];
    const listItems = data.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

We have some "data store" like `data` and `.map` which render this structure.

My problem is performance.

**How react works with it**: when we have 10 000 rows in `data` and change position for one / add new / remove some one it run `.map` for every of 10k rows and check diffs. It is very long operation (~600ms).

**What I wont**: When I remove for example 100th element (same with Add / change order), I know that only ONE element is changed, React have to remove only THAT element from DOM and Virtual DOM and don't run `.map` again with 10k rows with changes detector.

Any ideas / libs / Technics how to do something like that (prevent checking whole array)?

Comment: You could only render the elements that are needed for your current viewport. You could also just apply `display: none;` to the element you are wanting to remove without actually removing (depending on your use case).

Comment: @JohnRuddell question is completely different. I need Add and Change ordering at least.

Comment: which is why i said depending on your use case. The browser will probably have issues rendering that many elements into the DOM. Your issue is more related to that. I would just limit what you render based on your viewport. only like X number of rows before and after the current viewport, with a padding at the top to simulate the size of the scroll container.

Comment: @JohnRuddell lol, browser is extremely easy to draw 10k divs and using for ex `appendChild` adds new elements. But react muse run `.map` and its HEAVY operation and this is problem. In vanilaJS this example takes ~10ms, in react ~600ms to move 1 div

Answer (score -1):

For everything above a few hundert items, you should use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or [react-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list). This saves you the headache to maximize performance and also reduces the amount of work the browser has to do. It only renders views within the current viewport (visible items) and some below and above to enable smooth scrolling. All your performance problems will be solved with that, because the map function will not be called for all 10 000 items. Changing or deleting items will be instant.

Comment: I need whole list of items on page. Question is completely different

Comment: Even on a whole page, you can hardly render 10 000 items. So most items are not displayed anyway or how does your view look like?